# Run JQuery function just once per visit

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I have a simple JQuery function - just fadeouts a div on the index page:

```
$('#startup').delay(1500).fadeOut(2000);
```

This is just a startup screen with a message the user sees when they first come to the site.

I was wondering if anyone knew a way to have the startup message display only once per visit. EG: if the user navigates back to the index page from say the aboutus page I do not want the startup div to appear again.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the time of the visit in localStorage and just check it.

```
var now = (new Date()).getTime();
var lastTime = 0;
var lastTimeStr = localStorage['lastTime'];
if (lastTimeStr) lastTime = parseInt(lastTimeStr, 10);
if (now - lastTime > 24*60*60*1000) {
     // do animation
} 
localStorage['lastTime'] = ""+now;
```

EDIT : I made a fiddle demonstrating it :

http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/jAjLB/

You'll see the animation the first time, but not the second one, except if you wait for one minute (you could set it to a few hours for your site).

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/9RRyf/) demonstrating it. It works. But you have to wait 24h in order to see the alert again (you can adjust it in the code).

Comment: Thanks dystroy - issue is my original code $('#startup').delay(1500).fadeOut(2000); no longer works

Comment: No plugin required. I edited with a demonstration. Pay attention to the fadeIn I added to start the animation.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to a similar problem and this worked as a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set a cookie that can be checked to see if this is the first visit.

This could be set to expire on end of session if you want it it show 'per visit'.

Answer (score 1):

I would use localstorage for this... Cookies are sent with the pages headers and there is no need to use them if the server does not care about this value.

```
 /* Here are some utility localStorage functions */
    function store_data(data, key) {
        if (!window.localStorage || !window.JSON) {
            return;
        }
        key = key || data_key;
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    function get_data(key) {
        if (!window.localStorage || !window.JSON) {
            return;
        }
        key = key || data_key;
        var item = localStorage.getItem(key);

        if (!item) {
            return;
        }

        return JSON.parse( item );
    }

    function remove_data(key) {
        if (!window.localStorage || !window.JSON) {
            return;
        }
        key = key || data_key;
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
   /* and the check */ 
   var now = (new Date()).getTime(),
       then = parseInt(get_data('last_visit'), 10) || 0,
       diff = now - then;
    if( diff > 24*60*60*1000 ) {
       $('#startup').delay(1500).fadeOut(2000);
       store_data('last_visit', (new Date()).getTime());
    }
```